# Javascript function in AJAX response in button onClick

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

How to run JavaScript from buttons onClick in an AJAX response?

I've a HTML `div` element which is loaded from an ajax. Within this `div` there is an `<button>` with an attribute onClick defined to run a javascript function. The full response looks like this:

```
<div class="Stuff">
<p>FooBar</p><button onclick="openMenu('Hello')">open</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function openMenu(name) {
    console.log(" You clicked: ", name);
    }
</script>
```

So, how to execute the sript on button click? In the console is says:

```
ReferenceError: openMenu is not defined
```

The `div` and the `script` get inserted via an `XMLHttpRequest` and `document.getElementById("content-row").innerHTML = this.responseText` where "content-row" is a div as well.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where are you placing this `<script>` tag?

Comment: make sure div is being added before the script tag.